# How to set title tag in magento2.1

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

As suggested by our SEO guys, they wanted to show title tag on product detail page's thumb images. I am able to manage other image's title tags on the same page but not able to set title tag here. Here is screenshot for more idea. http://nimb.ws/hX74Fr

Following files I have modified and added title but no luck.
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php
getGalleryImagesJson() function, added title tag

/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Data.php
getOptions($currentProduct, $allowedProducts) function, added title tag.

I assume above files and willing to override if these are the files only. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update on this? Were you able to resolve?